# Multirow in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to replace the buffer column with multirow(), so the value of buffer is exactly in the middle. How should I do it?

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{@{}llcccccccc@{}}
\toprule
 &   &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Disjoint}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Blurry10}}\\
\cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){3-6} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){7-10}

 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{CIFAR-100}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{CIFAR-100}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} \\
\cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){3-4} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){5-6} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){7-8} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){9-10}

\textbf{Buffer} & \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F}  & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F}  \\
\midrule
       &   EWC    &      &      &      &      &      &      & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
       &   RWalk  & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
500    &    EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
       &   RWalk  & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
       &    EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
       &   RWalk  & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\midrule
   &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
  &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
1000   &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
  &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
 &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
 \midrule
  &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
   &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
   &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
2000  &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
  &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
   &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Accuracy and forgetting of all the experiments over 3 seeds.}
\label{tab:tabular_data}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: First you should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) instead of code fragment, the second, in `tabularx` table at least one column had to be of `X` type.

Comment: Does the fact that you're using a `table*` environment instead of a `table` environment signify that your document employs a two-column layout? Please advise.

Comment: You are looking for this macro: `\multirow` (from [multirow](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) package). In your case, `\multirow{6}*{<content>}` in the first cells of each group should do; `6` corresponds to a no. of rows to merge. See the linked manual for more info.

Comment: Multirow works by overlapping other (lower) rows.  You can achive the same effect using `\raisebox`, but would have to do all the calculations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason for using a `tabularx` environment for the material at hand, as (a) automatic line-breaking within the cells is neither necessary nor desired and (b) there's no need to force some of the columns -- say, the 8 data columns -- to have the same width.

I recommend that you use an ordinary `tabular` environment, that you drop the `\scriptsize` directive, that you get rid of *italics* and **bold-facing** in the header cells, and that you replace the interior `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace`.

That said, if you could make the "TinyImageNet" headers a bit shorter, the overall look of the table would improve noticeably.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*} % will be placed at top of page b/c 'twocolumn' is in effect
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{8}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Buffer & Method & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Disjoint} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Blurry10} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-10}
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CIFAR-100} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TinyImageNet} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CIFAR-100} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{TinyImageNet} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(l){9-10}

 & & Acc & F & Acc & F & Acc & F & Acc & F  \\
\midrule
500   &   EWC        &      &      &      &      &      &      & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
      &   RWalk      & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
      &    EWC       & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
      &   RWalk      & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
      &    EWC       & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
      &   RWalk      & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\addlinespace
1000 &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\addlinespace
2000 &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     &    EWC        & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     &   RWalk       & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Accuracy and forgetting of all experiments over three seeds.}
\label{tab:tabular_data}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table body should be something like this:

```
    \begin{table*}[!ht]
\centering
%\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{@{}XXcccccccc@{}}
\toprule
    &   &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Disjoint}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Blurry10}}\\
    \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){3-6} 
    \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){7-10}

    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{CIFAR-100}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{CIFAR-100}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} \\
    \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){3-4} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){5-6} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){7-8} \cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{0.5em}){9-10}

\textbf{Buffer} & \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F}  & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F} & \textbf{Acc} & \textbf{F}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{500}
    &   EWC      &      &      &      &      &      &      & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk    & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC     & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk    & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC     & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk    & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{1000}
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
 \midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{2000}
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
    &    EWC    & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
    &   RWalk   & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Accuracy and forgetting of all the experiments over 3 seeds.}
\label{tab:tabular_data}
    \end{table*}
```

For complete document (MWE) you need first to provide it in your question. We havent any information about your document (see @Mico comment).

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the words in the *top* row: it's the *header*, isn't it?

Also consider that `tabularx` with no `X` column doesn't work. You want `tabular*` instead. I suggest also `siunitx` and to use a small trick for making the subheaders the same width.

No need to use boldface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}

\newlength{\baksterlen}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\settowidth{\baksterlen}{\textit{TinyImageNet}}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=2.1]}
}
\toprule
{Buffer} &
Method &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Disjoint}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Blurry10}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6} \cmidrule{7-10}

& &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[\baksterlen]{\textit{CIFAR-100}}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[\baksterlen]{\textit{CIFAR-100}}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{TinyImageNet}} \\
\cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{9-10}

& & {Acc} & {F} & {Acc} & {F}  & {Acc} & {F} & {Acc} & {F} \\
\midrule
 500 & EWC   &      &      &      &      &      &      & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\midrule
1000 & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\midrule
2000 & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
     & EWC   & 92.4 & 54.0 & 93.4 & 82.4 & 95.2 & 90.9 & 95.2 & 90.9 \\
     & RWalk & 73.2 & 32.4 & 74.1 & 55.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 & 67.4 & 48.9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Accuracy and forgetting of all the experiments over 3 seeds.}
\label{tab:tabular_data}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]